# JavaScript - Object Functions

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object that's defined like this:

```js
const test = {
  myFirstFunction: () => {
    console.log('MyFirstFunction called');
    this.mySecondFunction('data');
  },

  mySecondFunction: (param) => {
    console.log('MySecondFunction called ' + param);
  }
};

test.myFirstFunction();
```

When I run this code, I receive an error that says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: this.mySecondFunction is not a function".

I don't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fat arrow functions don’t receive `this` from the call site, but from their surrounding scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow function doesn't have own `this`, it defaulty points to parent `this`.

In your `myFirstFunction & mySecondFunction` parent is `window`. when you call `this.mySecondFunction()` is actually looking for `window.mySecondFunction()` which is not there. That's why it throwing an error.

Change it to normal function, it will work fine.

```js
const test = {
  myFirstFunction: function() {
    console.log('MyFirstFunction called');
    this.mySecondFunction('data');
  },

  mySecondFunction: function(param) {
    console.log('MySecondFunction called ' + param);
  }
};

test.myFirstFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) states that:

> Arrow functions does not have its own bindings to "this", and should
> not be used as methods.

> Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within.

Thus in this case the "this" will not be the "test" object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that arrow functions don't bind their own `this` context, instead `this` will still be `window`

Try `test.mySecondFunction('data')` instead

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not bind their own **this**, they inherit their this from the parent scope ("lexical scoping").

So, in regular functions the scoped is bound to the global one by default. arrow functions on the other hand, do not have their own this but they inherit it from the parent scope, (in this case the global one)

```js
const test = {
  myFirstFunction: function() {
    console.log('MyFirstFunction called');
    this.mySecondFunction('data');
  },

  mySecondFunction: function(param)  {
    console.log('MySecondFunction called ' + param);
  }
};

test.myFirstFunction();
```